# Не обновляются данные QSqlRelationalDelegate из связанной таблицы

Tags: c++, qt

Есть окно с двумя виджетами `QTableView` и кнопкой, при нажатии которой в модель второго `QTableView` вносятся изменения, то есть меняется значение поля, которое отображается в первом виджете вместо foreign key. При этом соответствующие значения первого `QTableView` также изменяются, но значения в делегате `QSqlRelationalDelegate` нет. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Файл main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db1.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    db1.open();

    QSqlQuery("CREATE TABLE test (a integer primary key, b integer)");
    QSqlQuery("CREATE TABLE test2 (a integer primary key, s text)");
    QSqlQuery("INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1);");
    QSqlQuery("INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b');");

    QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(0, db1);
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);;
    model->setTable("test");
    model->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("test2", "a", "s"));
    model->select();

    w.ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    w.ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(w.ui->tableView));

    QSqlTableModel *model2 = new QSqlTableModel(0, db1);
    model2->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);;
    model2->setTable("test2");
    model2->select();
    w.ui->tableView2->setModel(model2);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Файл mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public slots:
    void bClicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Файл mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtSql>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(bClicked()));
}

void MainWindow::bClicked()
{
    qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel*>(ui->tableView2->model())->submitAll();
    qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel*>(ui->tableView->model())->select();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

На форме, соответствующей файлу mainwindow.ui, находятся два виджета `QTableView`: tableView и tableView2, и кнопка pushButton.

Comment: А результат выполнения `(ui->tableView2->model())->submitAll();` вы проверяли? Может внесённые изменения не записываются?

Comment: @aleks.andr Сейчас проверил — возвращает `true`. Да и данные в первом `view` же изменились, не меняются только значения в списке делегата. Я уж его и `QQSqlRelation` и заново добавить пробовал, а все равно, те же значения, что и до нажатия кнопки.

Comment: По-пробуйте будет ли работать не со связью ключь-ключь, а поле-ключь то есть `model->setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("test2", "a", "s"));`

Comment: @Cerbo этот код вообще уберёт `QSqlRelation`, так как в модели всего два поля, а индекс начинается с 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После просмотра исходного кода Qt нашёл, в чём была ошибка.

Делегат получает данные из модели таким образом: `sqlModel->relationModel(index.column())`. Эта модель `relationModel`, соответствующая главной таблице (test2 в моём примере), хранится во внутреннем объекте `QRelation`. При добавлении новой связи `QSqlRelation`, которая ставится в соответствие объекту  `QRelation`, объект `QRelation` инициализируется, и инициализирует модель, вызывая `model->select()`, но только один раз. Поэтому при обновлении `QSqlRelation` эта модель не обновляется и соответственно делегат получает «старые» данные.

Решение, очевидно, состоит в том, чтобы самостоятельно обновлять все модели `relationModel`. Правда, в общем случае непонятно, сколько связей было добавлено (это значение приватное) и неизвестны номера полей со связями, поэтому нужно ещё при каждом добавлении связи, добавлять номер поля, например, в вектор. Все эти исправления можно делать, унаследовав класс от `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. Код:

```
MyRelModel::MyRelModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db)
    :QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent, db), relColumnIndices(0)
{
}

void MyRelModel::setRelation(int column, const QSqlRelation &relation)
{
    relColumnIndices.append(column);
    QSqlRelationalTableModel::setRelation(column, relation);
}

void MyRelModel::updateRelations()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < relColumnIndices.size(); i++) {
        QSqlRelationalTableModel::relationModel(relColumnIndices.at(i))->select();
    }
}
```

Далее, когда нужно обновить модель `QTableView` нужно дополнительно вызвать метод `updateRelations()` и тогда ошибки не будет.